# how to attach two strings from different lists with respect to the range of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to attach two strings from different lists .

```
list1 = ['dir1/dir2/c/', 'dir1/dir2/java/', 'dir1/dir2/python/']
list2 = [['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], ['java1', 'java2', 'java3'],['python1','python2']]
```

For every item in list1, I need to join the items in list2.

output:

```
dir1/dir2/c/c1
dir1/dir2/c/c2
dir1/dir2/c/c3

dir1/dir2/java/java1
dir1/dir2/java/java2
dir1/dir2/java/java3

dir1/dir2/python/python1
dir1/dir2/python/python2
```

Code:

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        for k in j:
            print(i+'/'+k)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to get the index of the list you're processing. This way, you can choose which inner-list to iterate in your inner for-loop.

```
list1 = ['dir1/dir2/c/', 'dir1/dir2/java/','dir1/dir2/python/']
list2 = [['c1','c2','c3'],['java1','java2','java3'],['python1','python2']]

for i, li in enumerate(list1):
    for j in list2[i]:
        print(li+j)
```

Outputs:

```
dir1/dir2/c/c1
dir1/dir2/c/c2
dir1/dir2/c/c3
dir1/dir2/java/java1
dir1/dir2/java/java2
dir1/dir2/java/java3
dir1/dir2/python/python1
dir1/dir2/python/python2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` the two lists:

```
for d, l in zip(list1, list2):
    for s in l:
        print(d + s)
```

This outputs:

```
dir1/dir2/c/c1
dir1/dir2/c/c2
dir1/dir2/c/c3
dir1/dir2/java/java1
dir1/dir2/java/java2
dir1/dir2/java/java3
dir1/dir2/python/python1
dir1/dir2/python/python2
```